Exporting .tgs files with bodymovin
I am an animation designer on Adobe After Effects. Recently, I designed some animated stickers and tried to export them on bodymovin, but there are many layers (animations and effects) that were not successfully exported.
That is, the sticker is exported, but it is missing some layers, such as cc light sweep.
When I see some Channels specialized in this field, I know that they use the same effects and their stickers are exported successfully and completely.
